# Extract text from quotation marks in PHP

Tags: php, regex, quotations

I have a PHP page which gets text from an outside source wrapped in quotation marks. How do I strip them off?
For example:

```
input: "This is a text"
output: This is a text
```

Please answer with full PHP coding rather than just the regex...

Comment: I don't think you'll get many answers with that type of demand.  How about you post your full php code and we can help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: his question is pretty straight forward...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work quite nicely unless you have strings with multiple quotes like `"""hello"""` as input and you want to preserve all but the outermost `"`'s:

```
$output = trim($input, '"');
```

[trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) strips all of certain characters from the beginning and end of a string in the charlist that is passed in as a second argument (in this case just `"`). If you don't pass in a second argument it trims whitespace.

If the situation of multiple leading and ending quotes is an issue you can use:

```
$output = preg_replace('/^"|"$/', '', $input);
```

Which replaces only one leading or trailing quote with the empty string, such that:

`""This is a text""` becomes `"This is a text"`

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = str_replace('"', '', $input);
```

Of course, this will remove all quotation marks, even from inside the strings. Is this what you want? How many strings like this are there?

Comment: Unless the text between the outer quotes contains escaped quotes ... then you're in trouble :-)

Comment: True. I think $output = trim($input, '"'); as @PaulR.P.O. suggested may be better, but it's not clear from the question exactly what the use case is.

Answer (score 0):

The question was on how to do it with a regex (maybe for curiosity/learning purposes).

This is how you would do that in php:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(")(.*?)(")/i', '$2', $subject);
```

Hope this helps, 
Buckley

Comment: Why bother with `/i` when the expression contains no alphas?

Comment: Also why bother with capturing the `"`'s and it's also incorrect because you used non-greedy matching. You need to remove the `?` from your expression. Greedy matching is wanted here.